# Using boost's memory mapped files to store graph data

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files

I have an undirected graph with approximately 100,000 nodes and 200 million edges. Each edge has a small amount of data associated with it (5 ints). In previous versions of my application, which had much smaller graphs, it was not a problem to simply store all edges in a plain text file and read this file in its entirety. With my new, much larger graph, this quickly leads to memory issues seeing as the edge file itself is several gigabytes.

My graph applications is very straightforward: I simply pick a node and iterate its edges until the target nodes fulfills some criteria. Then I iterate the edges of this target node, repeating the process until a network of some small number of edges (single digits) is created.

Since I'm only utilizing a small portion of this graph at a time, it seems like a good application for a memory mapped file. However, I'm not sure how this would work implementation-wise. How could I access only the block of edges I'm interested in (i.e the edges connected to a specified node)? I was hoping to use boost's memory mapped file implementation, but any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard for doing this from scratch in C++. Even with the help of Boost. Because memory is limited on target platform. So you have to design your data struct very carefully. However I suggest you can try to utilize graph database like neo4j or spatial database like PostGIS. Which has implement the Graph data struct on file system already.

Comment: I didn't see spatial information implied in the question? Is there some way that spatial indexes are generically applicable to graph algorithms?

Comment: Spatial index can be used to resolve graph algorithm. Because the network data struct is well implement in spatial database like PostGIS.